# How to work with too many flash files?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have over 50 flash presentations all the same but with different images and sounds and data, i cant make those externals, the final output should be one file for each. 
If i want to change the design or the script then ill have to change 50 files and build them. 
how to do that in a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at sharing library assets at author-time: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd5f4b6c52cfaa4b126bdcdec13394f28cc2-8000.html#WSb03e830bd6f770ee-281c5dd312da59a893a-8000